# preserve spaces in string java, javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angularjs

I am sending data from java code to browser via http request.
data is something like this.

JAVA CODE OUTPUT

```
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |       |       |     3 (100)|          |
|   1 |  FOR UPDATE         |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   BUFFER SORT       |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| DD   |     4 |   160 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

But when I display it in browser it looks very bad.
Basically I have array of string which I am displaying in browser by using `ng-repeat`.
when I display it in java code it looks fine, but in browser not so good.
I did tried preserve white spaces but it did not help.
All i need to do is preserve all spaces in string.

```
{ 
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Any idea help?
BROWSER OUTPUT.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap it in pre tags, but the best way is to use HTML table cells.

```html
<pre>
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |       |       |     3 (100)|          |
|   1 |  FOR UPDATE         |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   BUFFER SORT       |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| DD   |     4 |   160 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a monospace font (so that every letter has the same width).
You can do this using css:

```
{
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```